# How can I make TypeScript error on missing mapped key?

Tags: typescript

This is what I have:

```js
type TransferType = 'INTERNAL' | 'WITHDRAWAL' | 'DEPOSIT'

type TransferEvents = Record<TransferType, Record<string, TypeFoo | TypeBar>>

export interface EventsTooltip extends TransferEvents {
  some: string;
  extra: number;
  keys: boolean:
  INTERNAL: Record<string, TypeFoo>;
  WITHDRAWAL: Record<string, TypeBar>; 
  DEPOSIT: Record<string, TypeBar>;
}
```

Is it possible to make TypeScript throw an error if I add another type to `TransferType`, like `'CORRECTION'`, but forget to add it to `EventsTooltip`? While also retaining the ability to be more specific for the value type (`TypeFoo` or `TypeBar`) in the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways.

One is to define `TransferType` in terms of an object type that has those `Record<string, TypeFoo>` etc. values, like this:

```typescript
interface TransferRecords { // Or whatever name makes sense
    INTERNAL: Record<string, TypeFoo>;
    WITHDRAWAL: Record<string, TypeBar>;
    DEPOSIT: Record<string, TypeBar>;
}

type TransferType = keyof TransferRecords; // Type is "INTERNAL" | "WITHDRAWAL" | "DEPOSIT"

export interface EventsTooltip extends TransferRecords {
    some: string;
    extra: number;
    keys: boolean;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEBiB7PZAbwFgAoZS5GAgLmRAFcBbAI2gG5yBfc0SWIhQZsAIThRi5KslYT6AZzBRQAcy5leZPuGjwkaKHBAKY0AEoQEeKABMFUilQCSAOVQBRc64CCAGXpLazsAHiUVEFUAGjQsXAIAPg0ZAHVnVAAJABFzHxT-QKsbWzDlNRiRCHEoJOkqLI8ABQB5AGV0wuCS8PLYsQlazXJyMDjDY1NoSuQAXmQAawh0PBhxkzMoIOKFDmQAej2+lGAHACI3T29-U+QAH2RTtMycvOu7h4aW9tRT4bIIAAemBsYGQ-D0QmQHgAbhBwApUAQADZgYCYZCAyAgexrSabIp2BykJyUBR4ZgQRRlSLJKiYoz0JhsTh1SiLdAKeisZEQYwabgacjWEygsBgACM9FQRnWUzGc3O7i8vj8p12lAOyBSNnmCiFeBFyDFACYpTK8dMFSlzM1XABxNUyDWHDxQKA2ZBwBy2CAKYBQCC2P7CpRG5GozD0GFwsAI8No2aOGRkin0U4A05RVkYgHKOD0AAsxqzJIWS05RqgjAgJZkF2VBWIAPoRBoeELxu43FrVCe2Vy+QCTZbcigaYzXZ7lE+bQ6w+Io-Hp0nPA0QA)

With that, `EventsTooltip` and `TransferType` can't get out of sync because they both draw on the same source information (`TransferRecords`).

If you didn't want to do that, I can't come up with a way to make the type fail, but I can come up with a way to make *using* the type fail, like this:

```typescript
type TransferType = "INTERNAL" | "WITHDRAWAL" | "DEPOSIT";

type BaseEventsTooltip = {
    some: string;
    extra: number;
    keys: boolean;
};

export type EventsTooltip = BaseEventsTooltip & {
    [key in TransferType]: key extends "INTERNAL"
        ? Record<string, TypeFoo>
        : key extends "WITHDRAWAL"
            ? Record<string, TypeBar>
            : key extends "DEPOSIT"
                ? Record<string, TypeBar>
                : never;
};
```

It's verbose and awkward, but it means that if you have some code like this somewhere;

```
const tooltip: EventsTooltip = {
    some: "x",
    extra: 42,
    keys: true,
    INTERNAL: /*...*/,
    WITHDRAWAL: /*...*/,
    DEPOSIT: /*...*/,
};
```

and later you add to `TransferType`, `tooltip` above will show an error because the new key won't be present (and can't be provided, because its type would be `never`). Hopefully that would reveal that you need to update the `EventsTooltip` type.

[Playground with `tooltip` working](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEBiB7PZAbwFgAoZS5GAgLmRAFcBbAI2gG5yBfc0SWIhQZsAIThRi5KslYT6AZzBRQAcy5leZcmCzCocEApjQRKALzIARAEkAcqgCiAJTsBBADJXkAH2sB1G1QACQARZzd-T28-K1DHAAUAeQBlIKsNHT1kcQUIRwA3CHAFVAIAGzBgTGRLUgoqBTxmCEVlNQ0ZCAAPZTh6JjZOaSoAawh0BXpWCohDDW5Msh7MPCgwZF1sZELisFKKqprLXPyikrK8SurkADIpBsoAbXH0ZFA0AyMTKDMAXXor2QPUgIAAJgprPYnK5oiMZJQAPzIZwQBBrMEAHiUKhAqgANGg9Pg8AA+eEIwETYG9YoQgJBMIRKJeCkIqjI1HoqBYnFqQlmcRQcmPdlUKlvEF0yFxRKpdJssUyTlojHY9p4gV6IUipVKgYQIpQBZLdFGDZgQ7Vei7C5W44PGRNFr0KzdKz4ikggz0AAsACZPaLXlNNlBGBAgzJoS53B56ERugmaHg-f7uNwo1RAiFwpFPAmk8Q5FBXe6M1nKPFkmlUIWEyWy1YKzwNEA)

[Playground with another element in `TransferType` causing `tooltip` to fail](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEBiB7PZAbwFgAoZS5GAgLmRAFcBbAI2gG5yBfc0SWIhQZsAIThRi5KslYT6AZzBRQAcy5leZcmCzCocEApjQRKALzIARAEkAcqgCiAJTsBBADJXkAH2sB1G1QACQARZzd-T28-K1DHAAUAeQBlIJjrFKSAWUcQ+wBxAFpHDxTHKw0dPWRxBQhHADcIcAVUAgAbMGBMZEtSCioFPGYIRWU1DRkIAA9lOHomNk5pKgBrCHQFelZOiEMNbiqyWcw8KDBkXWxkJpawNs7u3ss6hubW9rwunuQAMikg0oAG0NuhkKA0AYjCYoGYALr0MHIWaQEAAEwU1nsTlc0VWMkoAH5kM4IAhzuiADxKFQgVQAGjQenweAAfATCUjNii5i1MQEgmEIlEvJzCVQSWSKVBqbS1EyzOIoBygRKqNzwaj+Vi4olUulxeqZFLyZSaRN6Yq9MrVcbjYsIM0oIdjhSjJcwE8evQ7p9vS9ATJhqN6FYZlYGZzUQZ6AAWABMUbVYO2VygjAgyZkOJc7g89CIM0LNDw8YT3G42aogRC4UinkLxeIcigYYjlerlHiyTSqCbhdb7asnZ4GiAA)

It's clunky and I hope there's a better solution, but it works. :-)

Comment: Thanks!
Out of curiosity, what would it look like if `TransferType` was not used for other things elsewhere?

Comment: @Tobbe - :-) Funnily enough, I was just realizing that A) there was no reason not to include it, and B) even if it's used elsewhere, that doesn't mean you can't define it the way I was talking about. I've added it at the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic type that simply returns the generic after doing a compile-time check on the generic:

```
type TransferType = 'INTERNAL' | 'WITHDRAWAL' | 'DEPOSIT'

type TypeFoo = { __lock1: never };
type TypeBar = { __lock2: never };

type TransferEvents = Record<TransferType, Record<string, TypeFoo | TypeBar>>

type CreateEventsTooltip<
    // Compile-time check here.
    T extends TransferEvents,
> = T;

export type EventsTooltip = CreateEventsTooltip<{
  some: string;
  extra: number;
  keys: boolean;
  INTERNAL: Record<string, TypeFoo>;
  WITHDRAWAL: Record<string, TypeBar>; 
  DEPOSIT: Record<string, TypeBar>;
}>;

export type EventsTooltip2 = CreateEventsTooltip<{
  some: string;
  extra: number;
  keys: boolean;
  INTERNAL: Record<string, TypeFoo>;
  WITHDRAWAL: Record<string, TypeBar>; 
  // We're missing "DEPOSIT" so it errors
  // DEPOSIT: Record<string, TypeBar>;
}>;
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmE43NAvFAcgEkA5GAUQCUSBBAGQKgB9CB1ImACQBFKbX6jFgW7kACgHkAyhwIBYAFCLQkWDgBiAe01R8AbygB9QwBtNAYwDWARgBcUJBABumKAF8A3MpxrIAIQQ4XSgDYzMrACZ7Rxcgz0VvVXhkdExyFyRgFGDKCHNNOAATAB5k1AwsHAAaKFz8ouKUYDgASyQAcxrsSC0dFm6IALgAPmGEhRVoAGE4CARgCHSITJQYbRNgFrBixSg9qAB6A6gpzQBbMBaTCABaTbPocwALPMsoF9mAOl39mCgIAAeCyQhWyZVScCWKyqimGwRgXiUCkBYAKwCgkygUKya00Gy2wRmcwW2NW6022z0PxQ5wg9iarQ6iL2gOaCGiAFczgAjTDMqCWCAgFD2bnrOZIfmkCjUej2OoFEoMtqdXwQXrDfnsLi8fhy2p5RWNZoqro4IaaqA-USSGQweWGhrKjpm-yBTWKNwepEotEYnyk3H4sARQmzeaLDI48lbYpUhR7GkPekmpk-VmITk8vk-QXC0Xi5BSshUWh0B31JWp1UDDVajg8PgCcsGyvGxk183ujxWhOHY6sCAEWZQM4tFAoFVQABENukHGnUBpUBa6MwcAKKB+Rygc7tFaNzs7bpGiK9iKAA)

Edit: Also, if you want those index signatures with shallower typing back from you extending back when it was using interfaces, then you can change the `CreateEventsTooltip` type to look like this:

```
type CreateEventsTooltip<T extends TransferEvents> = T & TransferEvents;
```